# How to show a Pop-UP on link press?

Tags: html, css, popup

I have been working on this for quite some time on this without much results. Anyways, I saw this nice menu on a tutorial and I copied it, here it is:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Menu List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/checklist_menu_style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <h2>Our Menu</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Fresh Traditional Cod And Chips</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Old Fashioned Rice Balls</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Italian Spaghetti</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Spinach Salad</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Spicy Egg Special</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Chicken Tikka</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Chocolate Chou With Strawberry</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}


h2
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-top: none;
}

ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: none;
}

ul li span.list
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list
{
    color: #ccc;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li span.list:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background: #ff3663;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list:before
{
    left: 100%;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li span.list:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list:after
{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li span.icon
{
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li span.icon:before
{
    content: 'x';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 4px;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.icon:before
{
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Here is the result from the source code above:
[image]

As you can see, the menu is made to stay in the middle of the page, what I am trying to do, is to open just the menu as a pop up, not as a new page, when someone clicks a link on my home page. Also, it should blur the bacgkround when the pop up is open and to close it, the user should click somewhere else on the page...Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to write custom jQuery or Java Script for that to open and close pop-up.

Comment: @KuldipKoradia I take your word, but I saw others using visibility: hidden; I don't know if this would be useful or work in this case.

Comment: yes, you can use any thing visibility: hidden; or display: none; but on condition you have to add a custom script for toggle a class to main container and by using that class you can hide and show this pop-up. it's all about conditional CSS based on class toggle

Comment: @KuldipKoradia ok, good to know but even if they can be used,I still don't know how toimplement it...So, I am still going to wait for a response, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some code for you

```js
function showMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "block";
}
function closeMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="open-menu" onclick="showMenu()">Open</button>
 <button class="open-menu" onclick="closeMenu()">Close</button>
```

You have to display its property to none. then on a button click it will appear and on another button click it will dissappear. Here is how it will look

```js
function showMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "block";
}
function closeMenu() {
  document.querySelector(".menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: green;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  background-color:#fff;
}


h2
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-top: none;
}

ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: none;
}

ul li span.list
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 5px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list
{
    color: #ccc;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li span.list:before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    background: #ff3663;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list:before
{
    left: 100%;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li span.list:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.list:after
{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

ul li span.icon
{
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #262626;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li span.icon:before
{
    content: 'x';
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 4px;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: 0.25s;
}

ul li input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ span.icon:before
{
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button class="open-menu" onclick="showMenu()">Open</button>
    <div class="menu">
        <h2>Our Menu</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Fried Fish With Souce</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Fresh Traditional Cod And Chips</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Old Fashioned Rice Balls</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Italian Spaghetti</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Spinach Salad</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Spicy Egg Special</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Chicken Tikka</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="list">Chocolate Chou With Strawberry</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <button class="open-menu" onclick="closeMenu()">Close</button>
</body>
```

You can also make a link on top right corner of the menu with absolute positioning for closing it

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks. Although you helped me a to I am still wondering how I can make it responsive, like after a certain amount of width, the menu should decrease in dimension...

Comment: You just decrease the font size and padding in media queries